# how to show differences between some or all files? GIT

Tags: git

As in the subject: how to show differences betwen some or all files?

Sorry i've screwed up my question. I meant differences betwen branches for one or multiple or all files.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Or perhaps a bit more helpful:

```
git diff <commit1> <commit2> -- path/to/file.cpp path/to/anotherfile.cpp path/to/subdir
```

You can also (in e.g. bash)

```
git diff {<commit1>,<commit2>}:path/to/file.cpp
```

This way you can even

```
git diff <commit1>:path/to/file.cpp <commit2>:path/to/anotherfile.cpp
```

which is quite insane powerful, IMHO.

Replace `<commit1>` and `<commit2>` by any name of tag, branch (local or remote) or direct sha1 hash of a commit (this is known as a *commit-ish*)

To get really funky, you can specify tree-ish or blob hashes if you want. Do something completely silly with this for a sample:

```
$ git ls-tree HEAD^ | grep blob | sort -R | head -2
100644 blob 27785581e788049ac805fab1d75744dd7379735d    .gitignore
100644 blob 2821a5271ffd8e6b11bb26b8571f57e88ab81f38    TESTING

$ git diff --stat 2821a5271ffd8e6b11bb26b8571f57e88ab81f38 aa96765714a3058068c4425d801fab4b64e26066
 ...f38 => aa96765714a3058068c4425d801fab4b64e26066 |  155 +++++++++++++++++---
 1 files changed, 135 insertions(+), 20 deletions(-)
```

Now you won't usually do this, unless you have several versions of the 'same' file in you repo (which is iffy, if you ask me).

Comment: The best one is the third: 
`git diff <commit1>:path/to/file.cpp <commit2>:path/to/anotherfile.cpp`

Answer (score 15):

```
git diff
```

Will show you the pending modified changes of un committed files

[Review the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) on this command for the many different ways you can use it to see the differences between files

Comment: Or git diff <filename>

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vauge, but i think you are looking for:

```
git diff
```

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html